# Ionic 4 - Form validation with ion-item

Tags: forms, validation, ionic-framework, ionic4

Wrapping an `ion-input` in and `ion-item` shows a different color border bottom if the field is valid or invalid but this doesn't work on an iPhone. Is there anyway to get this feature on mobile devices ?

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-input formControlName="email" name="email" type="email"></ion-input>
</ion-item>

this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.email, Validators.required])],
    password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(6), Validators.required])]
});
```

Comment: please update your code... It's require .ts code to understand you setup validation or not.

Comment: Added the ts code but as I said, this works on desktop but not on mobile. Tested on iPhone.

Comment: <ion-item [class.ion-invalid]="email.hasError('required')">

Comment: If you change css properties of the ion-item you can have a highlight in validation time. ```--highlight-height: 2px;```

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation of ionic related to [input highlight](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item#highlight-height),

> ios has no highlight (technically the height is set to 0).

So to show the highlight, you should change the custom CSS of ion item, and explicitly indicate a highlight.

```css
ion-item{
 --highlight-height: 2px;
}
```